# Help me make this bash script pretty, or just less ghastly

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script, called *print_code.sh*, that takes a file name, and prints out the file with line numbers.

Here it is:

```
FILE=$1
line=0;
numLines=`wc -l $FILE | sed 's/ .*$//'`
digits=`echo "l($numLines)/l(10)+1" | bc -l`
digits=`echo "0$digits" | sed 's/\..*$//'`
for i in `cat $FILE | sed 's/ /_=SPACE=_/g'`; do
  line=`echo $line + 1 | bc`;
  i=`echo $i | sed 's/_=SPACE=_/ /g'`;
  printf "%${digits}d | %s\n" $line "$i"
done
```

Here is a silly source file in an imaginary language:

```
var x = 1
var y = 2
var z = 3
func dostuff {
  var a
  var b
  x = x + 1
  y = y + 1
  z = z + 1
  a = x + y + z
  b = a
}
```

Here is the output with the line numbers:

```
01 | var x = 1
02 | var y = 2
03 | var z = 3
04 | func dostuff {
05 |   var a
06 |   var b
07 |   x = x + 1
08 |   y = y + 1
09 |   z = z + 1
10 |   a = x + y + z
11 |   b = a
12 | }
```

There are (at least) two functional problems with *print_code.sh*:

- Any blank lines will be ignored - which will break the numbering
- If the source file contains tabs, the tab character will be treated like a newline character

Also, it is hackish in places, because I don't know bash that well - particularly substituting the space character with a placeholder *=SPACE=*, so we can iterate over each line using *for*.

**What is the best way this code can be cleaned up such that is not as hackish, and such that the above functional problems go away?**

Are there any other functional problems that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write a script to add line numbers, use cat -n or grep -n as others have suggested.

In general though, if you want to process a file line-by-line in bash, use "while read", eg:

```
 cnt=0
 cat "$file" | while read line; do
     cnt=$(($cnt+1))
     printf "%02d | %s\n" "$cnt" "$line"
 done
```

(You don't need to use cat and a pipe here, redirection works fine too)

A different way to work out the number of digits necessary is:

```
 digits=$(wc -l <"$file" | tr -d '\n' | wc -c)
```

(wc -l outputs the number of lines and a newline, tr removes the newline, wc -c counts how many characters that needed)

Comment: You can do `(( cnt++ ))` instead of `cnt=$(($cnt+1))`

Answer (score 9):

```
cat -n filename
```

Comment: As always, best to focus on the problem space instead of the solution space, as was done here! :-)

Comment: Best solution to the specific problem, so I've up-voted. I accepted another answer because it gave insight into problems with the script that will useful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

several ways, using tools such as nl, or awk

# nl file

# awk '{print NR,$0}' file

or just with bash

```
while read line; do echo "$i: $line"; i=$((i+1)); done < file
```

Comment: Ah, "read line" - That's a whole lot better than using for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
egrep -n . /dev/null file | sed -e 's/:/ | /'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed = filename.rb | sed 'N;s/\n/ \| /' | sed 's/\(^[0-9] \)/0\1/'
```